# Where have I made a mistake when using JS array as a function "repository"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, arrow-functions

I need to format numbers with custom number of decimal places. I use simple functions and I was trying to reuse already configured "formatting function".

Where do I have a mistake?

Edit: I've added full formatter setup, that uses http://numbrojs.com/ to format number in given language.

code:

```
const decimalPlacesDefaults = 2
const formatters: any = []

const createFormatter = (decimalPlaces = decimalPlacesDefaults) => {
    const formatter = numbro

    const language = formatter.languageData()
    language.delimiters = {
        decimal: ',',
        thousands: ' ',
    }

    formatter.registerLanguage(language, true)

    formatter.setDefaults({
        thousandSeparated: true,
        mantissa: decimalPlaces,
    })

    return formatter
}

const getFormatter = (decimalPlaces = decimalPlacesDefaults) => {
    // return createFormatter(decimalPlaces)   <-- when I uncomment this, everything works as expected
    const key = `f_${decimalPlaces}`

    if (formatters[key] === undefined) {
        formatters[key] = createFormatter(decimalPlaces)
    }

    return formatters[key]
}

const format = (value: string, decimalPlaces = decimalPlacesDefaultCount): string => {
    const formatter = getFormatter(decimalPlaces)

    return formatter(value).format()
}
```

test:

```
describe('format function to custom decimal places', () => {

    it('should reflect custom decimal places for all calculations', () => {
        expect(format('123', 3)).toMatch('123,000')
        expect(format('123', 1)).toMatch('123,0')
        expect(format('23.456', 2)).toMatch('23,46')  <-- fails here with '23,5' instead of '23,46'
        expect(format('11.24', 3)).toMatch('11,240')
        expect(format('456.78', 2)).toMatch('456,78')
    })

})
```

Comment: Please post the code of your formatter, maybe it uses some shared state? The `getFormatter` looks fine (apart from using `f_N` keys in an array).

Comment: use toFixed method

Comment: @Bergi I added `f_N` keys for debugging purposes - to be sure that my code really fulfill my intentions...

Comment: The problem is `const formatter = numbro`. The `createFormatter` function doesn't actually *create* a formatter. It just always returns the same one, and changes the defaults of this single instance.

Comment: @SteveTomlin thanks for tip, but `format` formats whole number according to selected preferences, `toFixed` will solve only part of the formatting.

Comment: @Bergi Is there a way, how could I solve it?

Comment: I don't see how that library allows creating multiple instances with different settings. (Maybe I was missing something in their API docs). You might have to completely wrap it.